Nodes and Gradient Texture
I have a Blender file that a friend shared with me. The Gradient it is producing is not as gradual as I would like. I know nothing about nodes, so I am kindly requesting help. I want to produce a gradual and even transition from black to white in the gradient produced in Blender.
In Photoshop, I am able to produce this gradual and even transition, but I need to accomplish the same result by altering this node setup. The closest I was able to come to this using the Gradient Texture node was to change the original setting (which was set to Linear) to Easing. It is close to Photoshop, but not quite there.
The first image is what I am after (which was made in Photoshop)
The Second shows the node setup and the gradient that it produces.



Well... blender is making a perfectly linear gradient, as it's expected to do. Maybe that is not what sounds visually appealing, but it's the smoothest ever. You could use a "float curve" node taking the "fac" of the gradient and control the curve as you like, then put the result of this "float curve" as the color of the next node. (Alternatively to the "float curve", you could test the "color ramp" and select one of the interpolation options other than linear)

From the red connecting lines in the node group which denote illegal connections, it may be that your friend is using a later version of Blender than yours (3.50). The current Blender version is 4.2.3 and the currently LTS version 3 is 3.6.17 so it might be worth asking which version he is using before going further.

As @DanielMöller already said, Blender produces a linear gradient. And what you show there from Photoshop is not even a real black to white gradient - it starts with (3, 3, 3) on the left instead of (0, 0, 0). But even if, in Photoshop itself you can choose between different interpolations when adding a Gradient layer: Classic, Perceptual and Linear interpolation - with Linear looking mostly the same as in Blender. And another thing is, I cannot see in the Blender screenshot if there is some Color Management involved.

Thank you @JohnEason
My apologies for responding late, as I have been away from the computer for about a week. Perhaps I should have started with what I am trying to do. I am trying to create greyscale images that I can use as depth maps. I will attach my friend's setup (which he did saya he made years ago) and the crude modeling that I have done based on the reference image that i put in the scene, so that you can see. The Depth map that I currently have (not what you see in Blender) for the subject in the foreground I will attach also. I made that using another software program.

@JohnEason here is the setup my friend created. And the depth that I currently have for one of the objects (the foreground figure) that I created in a different program (not blender).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OsqHOdmGOHliQYbD7d6iDWVdK39aXYTx/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vgVClroAPZvz1tiwHL2fpqkdmeQHFbCD/view?usp=drive_link

@JohnEason The depth map from a different program has too much contrast. The result when I go for printing is that the brightest point will make that part of the scene look abnormally out in front of the rest of the scene. I am using my friends' setup in hopes that I can get the depth for my depth map as accurate as the distance between the different objects in my scene that you see in the Blender file I attached.

@JohnEason I thought that this might be able to be achieved by having the smoothest transition in my gradient. But Daniel has told me that it is already the smoothest, so I'm hoping that I might be able to improve my depth map accuracy.
I think that because I am using a gradient to achieve this depth relationship between the objects in my scene, I am often running into the trouble I have explained.
My apologies, but my blender knowledge is quite basic.

@SaruPrasad I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with depth maps. Gordon Brinkmann who has also commented above has far more knowledge of them than I do. My original comment just pointed out that the red noodles on your original image denote illegal connections which are usually due to incompatible nodes, often because of different Blender versions.

Okay, @JohnEason, thank you for letting me know. And I will indeed follow up with Gordon.

Thank you, @GordonBrinkmann, for your response. John Eason mentioned that you might have more knowledge of depth maps than he does. I've provided a little more information about what I am up to in the thread that follows your original comments. Any help or guidance you can provide would be much appreciated.

@SaruPrasad Sorry, but I do not see any depth map in your scene. A depth map is a greyscale image which shows the depth (or distance from camera) with black meaning close to the camera and white meaning far from the camera. If your shader setup is supposed to create something like a depth map it is wrong because 1. The custom node group has "shader" inputs connected to "color" and "float" sockets which does not work, 2. it has transparency but this reveals "deeper" parts that should be hidden and 3. in Blender there exists a Z pass and a Mist pass which can both be used to get a depth map.
